# Why class <:<[-From, +To] needs to extends (From => To) in scala standard library?

Tags: scala

i am looking into scala's type level programming and have got some knowledge about it.But i have no idea why class <:< needs to extend from (From => To),i wrote the following code in REPL .

```
trait <:<[-T, +U] // just 'plain' generic trait

// an implicit object will looked up by compiler
implicit def implicitAgent[A]: <:<[A, A] = new <:<[A,A] {}

def myFunc[T,U](one:T, two:U)(implicit ev: T <:< U): Unit = {
    println(one, two)

class Base {
    override def toString: String = "base"
}

class Derived extends Base {
    override def toString: String = "Derived"
}

myFunc(new Derived, new Base)
```

and it works and prints:

```
(Derived,base)
```

So my question is what's the class <:<'s design decision?why it needs to extends From => To ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that way `implicit ev: T <:< U` also acts as an implicit conversion from `T` to `U` that can automatically upcast any value of type `T` to type `U`.

With `<:<` defined in `Predef`:

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> def myFunc[T](t: T)(implicit ev: T <:< Foo): Foo = t
myFunc: [T](t: T)(implicit ev: T <:< Foo)Foo
```

With your `<:<` :

```
scala> trait <:<[-T, +U]
defined trait $less$colon$less

scala> implicit def implicitAgent[A]: <:<[A, A] = new <:<[A,A] {}
implicitAgent: [A]=> A <:< A

scala> def myFunc[T](t: T)(implicit ev: T <:< Foo): Foo = t
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : T
 required: Foo
       def myFunc[T](t: T)(implicit ev: T <:< Foo): Foo = t
                                                          ^
```

Once you have a proof that a value is an instance of `U` (i.e. its type `T` is a subtype of type `U`) it's very likely that you will want to *use* that value as an instance of `U`, otherwise why did you need the proof in the first place? If `<:<` is a function you can do that automatically.